# One or more tables if modelling different type of data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

I am trying to find the best way to model the following problem.

I have Users and Tasks models in Rails. Users complete one task per day.

So far my two tables are:

- Users (Name, Email, Password)
- Tasks (Weekday, Task name, e.g. Monday - Running, Tuesday - Reading, Wednesday - Writing, Thursday - Make a list of things you did today, etc.)

Each task might require a separate screen depending on what is required (e.g. write some text for the "Running" task versus make a list of Articles for the "Reading" task).

I generally, would like to either write something or make a list of things depending on a given task.

What I am stuck at is how to model that Task Detail table (or two or more tables)?
Should I have a separate table for each Task? 
e.g. "Monday" table with "Status" field, "Tuesday" table with "Article" field, etc. etc.

Or have one table with "Status" field ad use this one field to write text in as well as to make a list of things.

Hope this makes sense. Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: I think you need to read an [SQL tutorial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your subtasks are tasks in their own right.

> Should I have a separate table for each Task?

No.

It's either some kind of subtask table, or re-using the task table for subtasks too, by adding a nullable parent_id.

Comment: But there's also the issue of the thing-specific payload: what article to read, how many km to run, what to write about, ...

Comment: @Mu: yeah. I'd rather not begin to imagine the number of tables he'll have if he normalizes each and every one of them. :-)

Comment: Normalization isn't always practical. Sometimes you have to go with a multi-purpose `varchar` to get something usable. I think part of his problem and confusion is how to handle this part of it.

Comment: Yep. `name varchar, details text`, or something to that effect, sounds quite reasonable here.

Comment: Preferably with some CHECK constraints to provide some minimal sanity checking.